# python: How can I test for @unittest.expectedFailure for a specific type of error?

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy

consider this test function

```
    @unittest.expectedFailure
    def test_add_existing_user(self):
        user = User('test_add_existing_user', 'welcome')
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        self.assertEquals(1, len(User.query.all()))

        db.session.add(User(user.email, 'welcome'))
        db.session.commit()
```

This test will fail with `IntegrityError` because user email column has `unique=True`

This test work fine, but what I need to check if the error my test encountered is `IntegrityError`, Is there a way to test/validate the error that was raised?

Because Error might occur much before the last statement is executed and then we would have a false positive in our test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `self.assertRaises` to make sure a specific error is raised.

```
def test_add_existing_user(self):
    """
    Checks that unique constraints return an IntegrityError.
    """
    user = User('test_add_existing_user', 'welcome')
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    self.assertEquals(1, len(User.query.all()))

    db.session.add(User(user.email, 'welcome'))
    self.assertRaises(IntegrityError, db.session.commit)
```

Comment: This will not work I believe since `IntegrityError` is an ERROR and not an EXCEPTION. I tried and saw `IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) column email is not unique`

Comment: After looking through the unittest code, I don't think you are correct about that.  Can you try it and post the output?  Make sure the second argument to self.assertRaises is a callable like in my answer.

Comment: you know, you are actually right, I tried exactly the same way and it worked, thank you so much for your time and effort !